# Combine array of dates sorted in ascending order into array of date ranges

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, date

I have one array of dates, I want to create object containing start and end by checking continue dates.
EX.

```
dateArray = [
                "2020-01-22T00:00:00.000Z",
                "2020-01-23T00:00:00.000Z",
                "2020-01-28T00:00:00.000Z",
                "2020-01-29T00:00:00.000Z",
                "2020-01-30T00:00:00.000Z",
                "2020-01-31T00:00:00.000Z",
                "2020-02-01T00:00:00.000Z",
                "2020-02-02T00:00:00.000Z",
                "2020-02-03T00:00:00.000Z",
                "2020-02-04T00:00:00.000Z",
                "2020-02-05T00:00:00.000Z",
                "2020-02-06T00:00:00.000Z",
                "2020-02-07T00:00:00.000Z",
                "2020-02-16T00:00:00.000Z",
                "2020-02-17T00:00:00.000Z",
                "2020-02-18T00:00:00.000Z",
                "2020-02-19T00:00:00.000Z",
                "2020-02-20T00:00:00.000Z"
            ]

myRequirement = [{
    start: "2020-01-22T00:00:00.000Z",
    end: "2020-01-23T00:00:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    start: "2020-01-28T00:00:00.000Z",
    end: "2020-02-07T00:00:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    start: "2020-02-16T00:00:00.000Z",
    end: "2020-02-20T00:00:00.000Z"
  }
]
```

I want to do this using in node.js.
I tried this using some nested for loops.
First i am running loop on main dateArray, Then checking is it first date or not, If it is first date then storing it as first objects start date, Then in next date case checking is it next most date of previous date or not.

```
let gapArray = [];
            let startEndObj = {};
            let tempStartDate;
            let tempEndDate;

            let tempNextDate;
            await asyncForEach(finalAvailablityDatesArrayOFi.availeblityDatesArray, async (availeblityDatesArrayOFi) => {
                console.log("availeblityDatesArrayOFi", availeblityDatesArrayOFi);

                if (!tempStartDate) {
                    console.log("In if");
                    startEndObj.startDate = availeblityDatesArrayOFi;
                    tempStartDate = availeblityDatesArrayOFi;
                    let oneDatePlus = new Date(availeblityDatesArrayOFi).setDate(new Date(availeblityDatesArrayOFi).getDate() + 1);
                    tempNextDate = new Date(oneDatePlus);
                    console.log("startEndObj", startEndObj);
                }
                else if (tempStartDate) {
                    console.log("in else");

                    if (new Date(availeblityDatesArrayOFi).getTime() == new Date(tempNextDate).getTime()) {
                        console.log("Do nothing!");
                        tempStartDate = availeblityDatesArrayOFi;
                        tempEndDate = availeblityDatesArrayOFi;
                        let oneDatePlus = new Date(availeblityDatesArrayOFi).setDate(new Date(availeblityDatesArrayOFi).getDate() + 1);
                        tempNextDate = new Date(oneDatePlus);
                    }
                    else {
                        startEndObj.endDate = new Date(tempEndDate);
                        gapArray.push(startEndObj);
                        tempStartDate = '';
                        tempEndDate = '';
                        startEndObj = {};
                    }
                }
            });
```

Thank you!

Comment: *'..I want to do this using in node.js'* and what is your progress, so far?

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov Well ... so far he's come here and asked us to do his thinking for him. My guess is that's about it.

Comment: @gforce301 : that's a huge leap forward from simply *wanting*, I must say

Comment: how you are calculating start and end time?

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov, Thanks to suggestion, Let me edit question and add my code as well, I did not add it because it was complex for loops.

Comment: @JayBhatt : it demonstrates that you've tried at least something rather than expecting others to do that for you.

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov indeed !

Comment: Is there a slight mistake in your expected result or did I miss something: your first range is supposed to include `2020-01-23` as an end date.

Comment: Typo? `start: "2020-01-22T00:00:00.000Z",
    end: "2020-01-22T00:00:00.000Z"` - should perhaps be `start: "2020-01-22T00:00:00.000Z",
    end: "2020-01-23T00:00:00.000Z"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a job for [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce).

---

**Note:**  hereafter assumption is made that few prerequisites are met:

- source array items are valid ISO-formatted date strings or others, parseable by `new Date()` constructor, otherwise should be brought to one of supported format
- source array items are sorted in ascending order, otherwise `Array.prototype.sort()` method must be applied in advance
- array items do not include time of the day part (or this part is exactly the same for all items), otherwise consecutive date records may happen to have difference greater than 864e5 milliseconds (1 day) and more complex comparison is required

---

You may walk through your array and compare current items with previous/following, once you have a gap greater than 1 day you push new range into resulting array or modify end date for the last one:

```js
const src = ["2020-01-22T00:00:00.000Z","2020-01-23T00:00:00.000Z","2020-01-28T00:00:00.000Z","2020-01-29T00:00:00.000Z","2020-01-30T00:00:00.000Z","2020-01-31T00:00:00.000Z","2020-02-01T00:00:00.000Z","2020-02-02T00:00:00.000Z","2020-02-03T00:00:00.000Z","2020-02-04T00:00:00.000Z","2020-02-05T00:00:00.000Z","2020-02-06T00:00:00.000Z","2020-02-07T00:00:00.000Z","2020-02-16T00:00:00.000Z","2020-02-17T00:00:00.000Z","2020-02-18T00:00:00.000Z","2020-02-19T00:00:00.000Z","2020-02-20T00:00:00.000Z"],
     ranges = src.reduce((res,date,idx,self) => {
      const rangeStart = !idx || new Date(date) - new Date(self[idx-1]) > 864e5,
            rangeEnd = idx == self.length-1 || new Date(self[idx+1]) - new Date(date) > 864e5
      if(rangeStart) res.push({startdate:date,enddate:date}) 
      else if(rangeEnd) res[res.length-1]['enddate'] = date 
      return res
     }, [])
     
console.log(ranges)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {min-height:100%}
```

Comment: Some of the logic is brittle, as noted in the caveats. I think it would be much better to implement a "[days difference](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+difference+in+days)" function to test if dates are contiguous rather than expecting 1 day to always be exactly 8.64e7 ms long.

Answer (score 1):

You need to be careful with this type of processing to determine all the business rules exactly. If the time component is not to be considered, then it should be removed, otherwise when comparing say 2020-01-01T00:00:00 to 2020-01-02T012:00:00 you will get a difference greater than 1 day but might not want it to be treated as the start of a new range.

For that reason, the "days difference" logic should be in a separate function, which also makes it easier to change date libraries if you're using one. The days difference is also signed, so make sure they are passed in the right order.

Otherwise, the following is pretty much the same as Yevgen's answer but a little more efficient I think as it only creates two Dates on each iteration instead of four.

```js
let dateArray = [
  "2020-01-22T00:00:00.000Z",
  "2020-01-23T00:00:00.000Z",
  "2020-01-28T00:00:00.000Z",
  "2020-01-29T00:00:00.000Z",
  "2020-01-30T00:00:00.000Z",
  "2020-01-31T00:00:00.000Z",
  "2020-02-01T00:00:00.000Z",
  "2020-02-02T00:00:00.000Z",
  "2020-02-03T00:00:00.000Z",
  "2020-02-04T00:00:00.000Z",
  "2020-02-05T00:00:00.000Z",
  "2020-02-06T00:00:00.000Z",
  "2020-02-07T00:00:00.000Z",
  "2020-02-16T00:00:00.000Z",
  "2020-02-17T00:00:00.000Z",
  "2020-02-18T00:00:00.000Z",
  "2020-02-19T00:00:00.000Z",
  "2020-02-20T00:00:00.000Z"
];

// Simple difference in days function
function daysDiff(d0, d1) {
  return Math.round((d1 - d0) / 8.64e7);
}

let ranges = dateArray.reduce((acc, curr, i, arr) => {

  // If first date, initialise first object
  if (!acc.length) {
    acc.push({start: curr, end: curr});

  } else {
    let d0 = new Date(curr);
    let d1 = new Date(arr[i-1]);

    // If difference greater than 1 day, end previous range
    // and start a new range
    if (daysDiff(d1, d0) > 1) {
      acc[acc.length - 1].end = arr[i-1];
      acc.push({start: curr, end: curr});
    }
  }
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(ranges);
```